# Python Converting columns to Datetime Not working

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, csv, datetime

I have df that with 3 columns on timestamps:

```
        X.  ... 
01/01/2013 12:00:20 AM. ...
```

so I have been trying to convert these columns into the DateTime format for some further analysis

When I run:

```
df.dtype()
```

the info comes back with each of these columns as objects. I have been reading the data in from a csv so they should be string objects.

When converting them to DateTime I have been using:

```
df['X'] = pd.to_datetime(df['X'])
```

and

```
df['X'] = df['X'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

But in every case, the kernel just keeps running and I am not getting anywhere... I want to be able to use these dates and times to calculate the difference between timestamp columns in minutes and such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Works on my end. Try restarting the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example that works with me.You can try it out in your own setup:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([["1/1/2016 12:00:20 AM","3/1/2016"],
                 ["6/15/2016 4:00:20 AM","7/14/2016"],
                 ["7/14/2016 11:00:20 AM","8/15/2016"],
                 ["8/7/2016 00:00:20 AM","9/6/2016"]]
        ,columns=['X','Y'])
print(df)

#convert one column
df['X'] = pd.to_datetime(df['X'])
print(df)

#convert all columns
df[df.columns] = df[df.columns].apply(pd.to_datetime)
print(df)
```